# The form appears to have no error in editing user page

Tags: python, django

I am using Django and editing the user page. When I press submit, it does not push thru. There was no error found and cannot locate where the problem lies. Hope someone can help me or point out my mistake.

The user profile page only contains first_name, middle_name, last_name, mobile_number, username and email. It does not contain, password. Thank you

**Forms.py**

```
class UserManagementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'mobile_number', 'password']

    ROLE_CHOICE = (
        (2, 'Admin'),
        (3, 'Super Admin')
    )

    ROLE_CHOICE_1 = (
        (1, 'Member'),
        (2, 'Admin'),
        (3, 'Super Admin')
    )


    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Jones', 'class': 'form-control ', }))
    middle_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'A', 'class': 'form-control', }))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Smith', 'class': 'form-control',}))
     mobile_number = forms.CharField(max_length=15, validators=[RegexValidator(
    '^\+[0-9]{1,3}\.?\s?\d{8,13}', message="Phone number must not consist of space and requires country code. eg : +639171234567")],widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '09123456789', 'class': 'form-control',}),
                                error_messages={'unique': ("Mobile Number already exists.")})

    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'jonesmith@gmail.com', 'class': 'form-control',}),
                        error_messages={'unique': ("Email already exists.")},)
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}),
                           error_messages={'unique': ("Username already exists.")},)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': '********', 'class': 'form-control', }))
    role = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=ROLE_CHOICE, attrs={ 'class': 'form-control', }))




    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ROLE_CHOICE_1 = (
        (1, 'Member'),
        (2, 'Admin'),
        (3, 'Super Admin')
    )
        super(UserManagementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            self.fields['role'].widget.choices = ROLE_CHOICE_1
    
    def clean(self):
        clean_data = super(UserManagementForm, self).clean()
        password = clean_data.get('password')
        confirm_password = clean_data.get('confirm_password')
    
    
    
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Password and Confirm Password does not match!"
            )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserManagementForm, self).save(commit=False)
        password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    MEMBER = 1
    ADMIN = 2
    SUPERADMIN = 3
    ROLE_CHOICE = (
        (MEMBER, 'Member'),
        (ADMIN, 'Admin'),
        (SUPERADMIN, 'Super Admin')
    )
    
    ACTIVE = 1
    DELETED = 2
    DEACTIVATED = 3
    
    STATUS = (
        (ACTIVE, 'Active'),
        (DELETED, 'Deleted'),
        (DEACTIVATED, 'Deactivated')
    )
    
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Some String")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length = 100, db_index=True, null = True, validators=[
        
            RegexValidator(
                regex='^(\+\d{1,3})?,?\s?\d{8,13}',
                message='Phone number must not consist of space and requires country code. eg : +639171234567',
            ),
        ])
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 100,validators=[MinLengthValidator(8),
            
        ])
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS, blank=True, null=True)
    
    # required fields
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'mobile_number']
```

**Views.py**

```
def super_user_account_edit(request, id=None):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserManagementForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Category updated successfully!')
            return redirect('super_user_account')
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    else:
        form = UserManagementForm(instance=user)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'user': user,
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/super_user_account_edit.html', context)
```

Comment: If you are running your code with `manage.py runserver`, you can check the console where this is running for any output. Does it show the `POST` request? If not, then check the JavaScript console in the browser for errors. If it does, then I recommend adding `print()` statements to your code to debug it to find out what is wrong.

Comment: p.s. To format your code correctly, you either need to indent EVERY line with an additional 4 spaces or surround the code with triple backticks. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting for details.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice As per console when I submit the form. no error specify but from URL /superadmin/userAccounts/edit/9 to ""GET /superadmin/userAccounts/edit/9?first_name=Porsche&middle_name=D&last_name=Jones&mobile_number=%2B63965459821&username=porschegt&email=test4%40gmail.com&role=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 14818"

Comment: I suggest adding `print()` statements or using a debugger to figure out why the profile doesn't get saved.

Comment: There was no error when i add print() in the else statement

Comment: Then you need to add more `print()` statements to track down the problem. See [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more debugging tips.

Comment: I got this error <ul class="errorlist"><li>username<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>... are you familiar with this? Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add the line `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.non_field_errors)) to the form in your template. This is because if a validation error occurs that is not tied to a specific field, it is only displayed if you include that line.

Comment: As per console when I submit the form. no error specify but from URL /superadmin/userAccounts/edit/9 to  ""GET /superadmin/userAccounts/edit/9?first_name=Porsche&middle_name=D&last_name=Jones&mobile_number=%2B63965459821&username=porschegt&email=test4%40gmail.com&role=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 14818"